# Pull-down menu like Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a menu for smartphones & tablets, but when I create it, it always overflows the content of my website.

The effect I want to achieve is the same as the [Twitter Bootstrap website](http://getbootstrap.com/) — When you open it with smartphones, you can press the button and the menu rolls down and pulls the content of the website.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="navbar-toggle hidden-lg collapsed" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="navbar-header" type="button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down">
        </span>                     
    </button>
    <div class="col-xs-12 dropdown-menu navbar-inverse" role="menu">
        <a class ="divider" href="#">Accueil</a><br />
        <a class ="divider" href="#">Centres d'Interets</a><br />
        <a class ="divider" href="#">CV</a><br />
        <a class ="divider" href="#">Contact</a><br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar). It's the official Bootstrap documentation. The examples are really good.

Comment: I think you want the navbar.. something like this: http://bootply.com/bcsNujMckL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the example from the documentation as a start:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    ...
  </div>
</nav>
```

You can find it [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar).

Comment: Damn, i never think to open the documentation with a smartphone resolution to see that ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. Courtesy:     http://bootswatch.com Adjust the menu according to your requirements

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <a href="../" class="navbar-brand">Bootswatch</a>
              <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-main">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="themes">Themes <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="themes">
                    <li><a href="../default/">Default</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>

                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="../help/">Help</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="http://news.bootswatch.com">Blog</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="download">Download <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="download">
                    <li><a href="./bootstrap.min.css">bootstrap.min.css</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./bootstrap.css">bootstrap.css</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="./variables.less">variables.less</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./bootswatch.less">bootswatch.less</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="./_variables.scss">_variables.scss</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./_bootswatch.scss">_bootswatch.scss</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>

              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="http://builtwithbootstrap.com/" target="_blank">Built With Bootstrap</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://wrapbootstrap.com/?ref=bsw" target="_blank">WrapBootstrap</a></li>
              </ul>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

In the above code,

```
<button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
```

Gives the desired effect when the window size changes in browser or on small screens (Mobiles and tabs).

[image]